# Is every compact $n$-manifold that immerses in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ smoothable?

Tags: general-topology, manifolds, differential-topology, riemannian-geometry, geometric-topology

Suppose that $M$ is a compact topological $n$-manifold, and $f: M \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ is a topological immersion, i.e. a local topological embedding.  Then is $M$ smoothable?  By that, I just mean 'does $M$ carry a compatible smooth structure as a manifold', the particular immersion doesn't have to be 'smoothable' here.

I feel like the answer is yes, but the problem is that if the original immersion doesn't behave well globally then you could get some problems trying to 'smooth its image' using tubular neighborhoods or something.  Maybe a partition of unity argument is enough, though?  I'm not sure how to deal with this problem in higher dimensions, or even in dimension $4$ which is the case I'm the most curious about.

This is related to a followup question in this thread:

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/390922/is-there-a-4-manifold-which-immerses-in-mathbbr6-but-doesnt-embed-in

Comment: You at least need $M$ orientable.  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/863960/orientation-of-hypersurface/864058#864058

Comment: @EricTowers It seems to be a result about embeddings, not immersions.  How did you want to apply it?  The real projective plane is non-orientable but immerses in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: Maybe we've come from different definitions of "smoothable".  The one I've used requires non-self-intersection, so embeddings.

Comment: @EricTowers Oh!  I'm asking if the -manifold- is smoothable, not the immersion!  Ok, gotcha.

Comment: I'm happy to remove my comments if we're coming from crossed definitions...

Comment: @EricTowers If you want, but it's not necessary xD  It will maybe clarify for others who interpret it that way.  I'm wondering if the condition is strong enough to imply that the (topological) manifold has a compatible smooth structure.

Answer (score 11):

Here is a possible strategy on how to find such an example (non-smoothable, immersible).

1. Find a closed 4-manifold $M$ with $k(M)=0$ (here $k$ is the Kirby-Siebenmann invariant), but non-smoothable (by Donaldson's theory or via SW invariants), $\pi$-manifold (see below).
2. Recall that $k(M)=0$ implies that $M\times {\mathbb R}$ is smoothable. For instance, if $M$ is the connected sum of two $E8$-manifolds, then $M$ is not smoothable (Donaldson), but $k(M)=0$ (since $k$ is additive under the connected sum).

**Definition.** A manifold $M$ is called a $\pi$-manifold (I think, the terminology is due to Hirsch) if $M\times {\mathbb R}$ is smooth and parallelizable.

Now, by the Smale-Hirsch theorey, each parallelizable manifold admits an immersion in the equidimensional Euclidean space. Thus, if you manage to find $M$ satisfying all these conditions, there is an immersion $M\times {\mathbb R}\to {\mathbb R}^5$, hence, a flat immersion $M\to {\mathbb R}^5$. At the same time, $M$ is not smoothable.

Unfortunately, $M$ equal to the sum of two $E8$-manifolds is not a $\pi$-manifold, so one needs to dig deeper. What you need is:

> A compact connected nonsmoothable 4-manifold $M$ such that $k(M)=0$, $M$ is spin (i.e is orientable and has even intersection form) and has zero signature.

Such $M$ **should be**  be a $\pi$-manifold. (Since spin implies almost parallelizable, while vanishing of the signature implies that $p_1(M)=0$,  together these **should** imply a $\pi$-manifold, see Proposition 8.4 of A.Kosinski, "Differential Manifolds". The caveat is that the proof that we get a $\pi$-manifold assumes that $M$ is smooth; it remains to be checked check if the proof can be modified to work with topological tangent bundle.)

I can neither find such $M$ nor verify that it is a $\pi$-manifold. It is worth asking about existence of such $M$ and if it is a $\pi$-manifold (provided it exists) on Mathoverflow if you are serious about the question.

Comment: Oh wow, this is very over my head D:  I can still try to reference-dig though, I'll get back to you after a couple days!  I was hoping there was some well-known algebraic trick for this one as in the smooth case.

Answer (score 7):

To complement Moishe Kohan's answer, if M is orientable and has dimension $>4$, if the immersion is locally flat (a technical condition required to induce a map on topological tangent bundles), then $M$ is smoothable.

This is an application of some big theorems of differential topology. Let's do the easy part first, if we have an immersion that behaves nice enough to induce a map on topological tangent bundles (sometimes called microbundles), then we can decompose the trivial rank (n+1)-microbundle on $M$ as the sum of the microbundle of $M$ and a rank 1 bundle. From the orientability of $M$, this must be a trivial rank 1 bundle.

Hence, stably the tangent microbundle of $M$ is trivial. One consequence of smoothing theory is that above dimension 4, smooth structures up to concordance are in bijection with lifts of the the stable microbundle to a stable vector bundle structure (up to some equivalence). Since the microbundle is stably trivial, it always has a lift (stably) to the trivial vector bundle. Hence, $M$ is smoothable. I will just note here that this argument implies all (topologically) stably parallelizable manifolds above dimension 4 are smoothable. For some reason I have not been able to find a statement of this kind, but it is an easy corollary of this stable statement of smoothing theory.

I am not sure if codimension 1 immersion always implies there exists a locally flat immersion, I think it is known that there is not necessarily one arbitrarily close, but these things can get very nasty so I wouldn't bet one way or the other.

Comment: Wow, nice result!  That handles a lot of the cases.  I have just been reading some of this stuff about microbundles, the classic stuff from the 50's and 60's, so it's cool to see it show up in a totally different context.

Comment: Yeah there shouldn't be one arbitrarily close, even in dimension $3$.  In dimension $4$ there is that theorem that you'll be smoothable everywhere except a single point; maybe the same can happen for immersions.